# Azure AD (MSAL) Authentication not working on ASP.NET core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have simple asp.net core app

Startup:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured.
            // By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications.
            // 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles'
            // This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token
            // JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            // Adds Microsoft Identity platform (AAD v2.0) support to protect this Api
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers();
    
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "LuloWebApiCoreMac", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "LuloWebApiCoreMac v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
         
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Program

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xx.com.co",
    "TenantId": "xx-c220-48a2-a73f-1177fa2c098e",
    "ClientId": "xx-3737-48a5-a6c0-7e3bc4f9a5c9"
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:44351"
      }
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

As you can see the Client ID is set

However when I do dotnet build and dotnet run and go to the site, I get this error:

```
OptionsValidationException: IDW10106: The 'ClientId' option must be provided.
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<TOptions>.Create(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<TOptions>+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
System.Lazy<T>.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
System.Lazy<T>.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
System.Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
System.Lazy<T>.get_Value()
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache<TOptions>.GetOrAdd(string name, Func<TOptions> createOptions)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<TOptions>.Get(string name)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiImplementation>b__0(JwtBearerOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsMonitor<MicrosoftIdentityOptions> microsoftIdentityOptionsMonitor)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions, TDep1, TDep2>.Configure(string name, TOptions options)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory<TOptions>.Create(string name)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<TOptions>+<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
System.Lazy<T>.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
System.Lazy<T>.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, bool useDefaultConstructor)
System.Lazy<T>.CreateValue()
System.Lazy<T>.get_Value()
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache<TOptions>.GetOrAdd(string name, Func<TOptions> createOptions)
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor<TOptions>.Get(string name)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, string authenticationScheme)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration) is showing a slightly different way of configuring it. Did you consult the documentation? Why did you tag this question as asp.net and .net? It doesn't look like you're actually using either of those.

Comment: yes I did https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg

Comment: You have not addressed all the points in my previous comment.

Comment: I am having an email exchange with one of the authors of the 4-2 sample. He says the sample is not working at the moment, and that they are updating the engine and the documentation at the moment. Imo the Microsoft Azure team seems unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the name you're trying to bind the configuration to. The error is saying it can't find `ClientId`.

In your case, this should be  `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");`

You can read more about the options pattern in ASP.NET Core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: The services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication has an overload method, that uses "AzureAd" by default. Please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiservicecollectionextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapiauthentication